# What are the Solfège names of the semitones between the basic do, re, mi, etc?

Tags: notation, solfege

What are the names of all the notes in a sol-fa scale, especially the chromatic notes between the basic Do, Re, Mi's.

Comment: I use a suffix of d (Dièse) to raise a note, and b (Bemolle) to lower a note. Thus C# is Dod and Db is Reb. Nice and easy.

Comment: Is this you personally, or is it a common method?

Comment: Sharps: Di Ri Fa Fi Si Li Do Di (♯1 ♯2 ♯3 ♯4 ♯5 ♯6 ♯7 ♯1) // Flats: Ti Ra Me Mi Se Le Te Ti (♭1 ♭2 ♭3 ♭4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭7 ♭1)

Answer (score 22):

per the first promising looking result from google...
<strike>http://library.thinkquest.org/05aug/01262/lessonsolfege.html</strike>

[EDIT: from Wayback Machine]

[http://web.archive.org/web/20090710170110/http://library.thinkquest.org/05aug/01262/lessonsolfege.html]](http://web.archive.org/web/20090710170110/http://library.thinkquest.org/05aug/01262/lessonsolfege.html%5D)

Chromatic Scale

Using sharps - Do, Di, Re, Ri, Mi, Fa, Fi, Sol, Si, La, Li, Ti, Do

Using flats - Do, Ra, Re, Me, Mi, Fa, Se, Sol, Le, La, Te, Ti, Do

Comment: This is one common system, but there are others, and in practice fixed do does not use accidentals for singing.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be some (depending on country, author or whatever) variants of the general idea to replace vowels by higher sounding ones for sharps and  by lower sounding ones (in extreme case always "u") for flats (which are also simply formed by attaching a "b" for "bemolle" in French, so si→sib).

In German wikipedia I found these replacements
do→di, re→ri, fa→fi and so→si, for sharps , ti→ta, la→lo and mi→ma resp. ti→tu, la→lu and mi→mu.

[English wikipedia article for Solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge) also provides some ideas.

Answer (score 6):

In [moveable-do solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Movable_do_solf.C3.A8ge), the usual practice is to indicate sharps with an *-i* vowel and flats with an *-e* or *-a* vowel. For example, a sharp *do* becomes *di,* flat *sol* becomes *se,* and flat *re* becomes *ra.*

There are chromatic variants of [fixed-do solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Fixed_do_solf.C3.A8ge) similar to the moveable-do system, but the usual practice in fixed-do is to sing the plain note name without alteration:

> In the major Romance and Slavic languages, the syllables Do (Ut for the French), Re, Mi, Fa, Sol, La, and Si are used to name notes the same way that the letters C, D, E, F, G, A, and B are used to name notes in English. For native speakers of these languages, solfège is simply *singing the names of the notes,* omitting any modifiers such as “sharp” or “flat” in order to preserve the rhythm.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 12-pitch chromatic solutions, there are also proposed solfege for quarter-tone systems. For example, here is a proposal for a [41-EDO solfege system](https://en.xen.wiki/w/41edo#Intervals).

For more information see: [Can tonic sol-fa cope with quarter tones?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104930/can-tonic-sol-fa-cope-with-quarter-tones/104942#104942)