# Siler 'international' solfege system. Pros, cons?

Tags: solfege

The principle is basically to assign different vowels to the different accidentals, and keep the consonatns from the Do Re Mi system.

Natural = a; sharp=e, flat=o, double sharp= i; souble flat = u.

So, a C major scale would be: Da Ra Ma Fa Sa La Ta Da;

a G major scale: Sa La Ta Da Ra Ma FE Sa;

D major: Ra, Ma, FE, Sa, La Sa, De, Ra,

And so on and so forth.

Now my opinion about this:

Pros:

-Accounts for all accidentas in fixed do solfege.

Easy to memorize.

Cons:

-Have to re-associate to the students who already use the Do Re Mi solmization.

Questions for the community:

1)Do you know if this system is used somewhere?

2)what could be potential benefits of learning this system?

3)What are some problems that implementing this might cause for the student?

3b)Could learning this system become a hindrance, in the sense that a student could  become too closed in this system and then having problem to comunnicate with other musicians who user ither the CDE or Do re mi systems?

Comment: Related [question](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/9932/2600)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  But, besides the consistent and more meaningful use of the vowels, you're also basing everything on C?  In traditional solfege, G major, G minor, C major, F# minor, etc., they all start on "Do."  It's all relative from there.

I learned solfege in HS and college and use it to this day (to assist myself and band members learning BG vocals, mostly).  Glad I put in the time then - personally couldn't imagine learning a new way.  But, to address your real question, not sure if this would be a better way to teach it, or not.  (Don't expect any compatibility between those who know the old way and the new!)

Comment: "they all start on 'Do.'" In *movable-Do* solfège, "Do" matches whatever the tonic is. But in *fixed* systems, "Do" is always C. (And, depending on the fixed system, sometimes Cf and Cs are, as well.)